# How to use a C#/VB Library in a Classic ASP site

Tags: asp-classic

In a classic ASP Website, how can I use a DLL that is a .NET 2.0+ C# and some times VB Library?

Is there any method we can use to consume such library?

---

**Added**

...in order to use it in a Hosting Environment?

Well, I can always create a **WebService** to serve as a "middle-men" but for such huge Libraries is impossible/takes long time... **is there a tools for it**? that reads the Assembly **and creates a Proxy class**, kinda what we do with WDSL today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could register this managed assembly as a COM component that could be invoked from the classic asp site using [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx):

```
regasm.exe /codebase somemanagedassembly.dll
```

You should also make sure that the assembly is [COM visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) so that the types it contains could be exposed.

Comment: that would be a no go in a Hosting Environment :(

Comment: Another option is to expose the functionality contained in this managed library as a standard web service (REST, SOAP, ...).

Comment: You could also take a look at `MSSoap.SoapClient` (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307033)